# How Google Cloud Run supports to connect different micro services and different databases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run

Assume I want to deploy multiple micro-services by using google cloud run and those micro services will be connected each other. My questions are follows

1. Does each micro-service deploy separately by creating google cloud run service
2. Then how each micro service call each other (by using public IPs)
3. How to connect different micro-service with different dbs such as Mongo DB, CassandraDb. Is there way we can create NoSQL Db in compute engine and access through google cloud run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does each micro-service deploy separately by creating google cloud run service

Yes, each microservice is individual and has it's own http/s endpoint if you need it.
If you need to deploy more more in bulk, you can always use a CI/CD tool.

> Then how each micro service call each other (by using public IPs)

When you deploy your service for the first time with an HTTP trigger you are provided with an unique url (similar to what happens with cloud functions). You can then invoke your service via HTTP as usual. 
Of course if you have many services, calling them blindly it's not the best option, I advice you to use a service mesh ([istio](https://istio.io/)) and/or an api-gateway ([cloud endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run)) in order o have better control and flexibility on your apis.

> How to connect different micro-service with different dbs such as
>   Mongo DB, CassandraDb. Is there way we can create NoSQL Db in compute
>   engine and access through google cloud run.

I don't see why not but please consider the list of this known limitations of cloud run (managed): [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues)
Basically it doesn't support a VPC connector, so you can't do it over a private ip. Also consider many of the managed db gcp offers, maybe datastore is good enough for you use case ?